# Codeigniter add Exceptions to Config class

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

Maybe, it's a bit silly, but does anybody thought about adding exceptions to Codeigniter Config Class(Library).
Not sure, it is(will be) a good practice, but i suppose throwing an exception instead of just returning false is better.

For example, if we have something connected with user payments.
Usually(?), we'll take some configurable data from codeigniter config files. Imagine, we've done a typical error specifying config index, and CI will return just false, which may cause some logic(!not syntax) error in this software.

Comment: DCrystal, are you talking about throwing an exception if the config item does not exist or throwing an exception if the config item is not within certain parameters?

Comment: Sean Vieira, i meant first case. Well, more obvious example is probably when we do:

// get some index from somewhere(form,uri etc)

$some_var = $this->config->item($some_index, 'config_opts');

// echo $some_var === false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would probably be best if you brought it up in the codeigniter forums. that way ellislab can see it...

> http://codeigniter.com/forums/